# What do I mention in the privacy policy for my game in Google PlayStore which doesn't collect data on its own but uses third party analytics software?

Tags: privacy-policy, data-collection

I have a game that does not collect/process any type of data on its own(I do not own/use servers to collect/process data). The game uses services like AdMob, Firebase and Google Analytics to collect analytics data(which includes data such as age, gender and interests of a user).

Do I need to mention in the privacy policy as if the game itself collects data? Or should I list the privacy policies of the services used to collect data and mention that while the game itself does not collect data, the services do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the collected data, simply disclose it in your Privacy Policy.

If you use third-party SDKs that may collect data from users, disclose those third parties in your Privacy Policy. You can mention each third-party you use and link to the Privacy Policies.